# Service not sinchronized

Tags: angular

I have a service that is used to call a **webapi**.

The webapi URL is read from a **local json file**.

The problem is that the service method calls the wrong webapi URL and I suspect that the cause is that the methods are called **before that de constructor code has finished the execution**.

This is the suspected code:

## constructor

```
  constructor(private http: AuthHttp, private router: Router, private paramService: ParamService) { 
    
    this.paramService.get_Config().subscribe(
      data => {
        
        this.baseUrl = data.ReportApp_WebApi;
      }
    );        
    
  }
```

## example method

```
Get_LavorazioneRicette() : Observable<any> {
    var url = this.baseUrl + "api/masterdata/get/LavorazioneRicette";

    return this.http.get(url, this.getRequestOptions)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base rule: Don't use subscribe in service. That always makes the code complex and difficult.

You don't need a constructor here. you can just do this.

```
getBaseUrl(): Observable<string>{ 
   if(!this.baseUrl){
     this.baseUrl = data.ReportApp_WebApi 
   }
  return Observable.of(this.baseUrl);
}

Get_LavorazioneRicette() : Observable<any> {
    return getBaseUrl()
        .map(baseUrl=> baseUrl+ "api/masterdata/get/LavorazioneRicette")
        .flatMap( url => this.http.get(url, this.getRequestOptions)
                             .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Above code is good when getting url is asynchronous, works well for synchronous too.
But localStorage is not asynchronous . So, no need to worry much . You can just do this. You dont even need to store the baseUrl .

```
Get_LavorazioneRicette() : Observable<any> {
const url = data.ReportApp_WebApi + "api/masterdata/get/LavorazioneRicette";
    return this.http.get(url, this.getRequestOptions)
                .map(response => response.json()
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```